# Magento - Duplicate Product programmatically / Set default Image?

Tags: image, magento, duplicates

I´m duplicating Products programmatically but I dont want the orgiginal Picture - I just want a default image which is on my server.

How do i do? I dont get it:-/

```
    $clone = $product->duplicate();
    $clone->setSku('Generator');
    $clone->setName('Ihre Konfiguration / Bestellung');
    $clone->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);   
    $clone->setStatus(1);
    $clone->setVisibility(4);
    $clone->setTaxClassId(2);
    $clone->setCategoryIds("93");
    $clone->getResource()->save($clone);
```

This must be the Code I tried it "before  $clone -> save " but how do I set the Path to imagefolder?

```
    $clone->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
    $clone->addImageToMediaGallery ($fullImagePath, array ('image','small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filePath = "../media/product/img_import/img.jpg";
$clone->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
$clone->save();
```